# Why isn't the Loop tool add-on turning the selection into a circle?

Tags: modeling, add-on

I'm trying to do a circle in a cylinder, I unchecked flatten as it was explain in the forum but it does nothing. I probably forget something.

[image]

It doesn't work if I put 100% influence, see the result:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the *Influence* is set to 0%. If you increase it to 100% the selected vertices will form a circle.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: it doesn't work. I re-edit my question with a screenshot of the result

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your mesh or your selection. Perhaps you've selected more than just the front facing faces or there are other issues with your mesh, e.g. duplicate vertices or internal faces?

Comment: I don't understand, I only selected the faces you see in the screenshot...I created a cylinder, then I added loops cuts and subdivision surface modifier, finally I selected faces.

Comment: Maybe the faces have to be real squares. Maybe I have to subdivide instead of add loop cuts?!

Comment: I've created a cylinder, used CTRL+R to add the loop cuts, selected the vertices and then applied the circle tool from loop tools.

Comment: It works when I create the cylinder, loop cuts and applied loop tools directly. But if I scale Z before creating loop cuts, that does what you see in screenshot.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this in a quick test, but you could try to apply the scale first using CTRL+A > Scale.

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: How exactly are you scaling the cylinder? In object or edit mode? Where is the Z axis in your screenshot (is it scaled in the direction of the caps)? What is your scaling factor (maybe it's negative)? Do you have proportional edit enabled?

Comment: Perhaps it would be the easiest if you could share your blend file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: THAT's IT!! When I scale in EDIT MODE, it works! Thank you

Comment: Great! If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.